# Is there a way to disable sending SNI records in a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, sni

I've tried using the `params` element:

```
<param name='java_arguments' value='-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false'>
```

Tried from code also with

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

Seen these threads but none of the suggested solutions worked:

- [SSLException during handshake while resuming cached session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188568/sslexception-during-handshake-while-resuming-cached-session)
- [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

But what I really want is to generally disable SNI even before the Java machine starts downloading the applet code.

Comment: The end-user is me & I have no control over the server part. The feature that I'm looking for is to be able to start the applet through https even if the server sends wrong information.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  It might pay to edit that information into the question.  Can you run the applet using appletviewer?  It *might* be easier to enable this property.  Is the applet trusted?  Do you have an URL for the page with the applet?

Comment: The applet is trusted, but even starting anew, the jvm process doesn't reach the point where to present you with the applet certificate. Actually, it just doesn't load the applet. Level 5 trace in the java console shows the first exception as being "Remote host closed connection during handshake" SSLException. And after that errors that cascade because it couldn't load the main class from the jar. The problem appeared since upgrading to jre 1.7. 

With appletviewer the applet runs with no problems.

Comment: I had a bit of progress. If I go in the Java Control Panel and I check __Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format__ the applet loads. Now, is there any way to make this just an one time option for this specific applet?