# how to set jsse.enableSNIExtension to false

Tags: java

I am trying to set jsse.enableSNIExtension property to false but each time when I try I get java manual.

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

I had problem mentioned in here [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized\_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wicked late, but here:

```
System.setProperty ("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following in command line to run Jenkins war file which is present in "c:\Jenkins"

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -jar c:\Jenkins\jenkins.war
```