# IntelijIdea 14 ssl handshake failure

Tags: svn, ssl, intellij-idea

I tried checking out code from svn command line on mac OS yosemite. Everything works fine.

When i try to add repository inside IntelijIdea nothing really appears. Looks like intelijIdea is caching the repository url and is throwing some SSLv3 vs TSL failure error. I have tried following links but nothing helped.

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5510351
[IntelliJ Idea doesn't work properly with svn update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691722/intellij-idea-doesnt-work-properly-with-svn-update)

I see this error

Subversion: (Accessing URL: https://XXXXX/svn/XXX) Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Please check Subversion SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1

Any advise will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The solution was that SVN server was sending a SSL certificate which needs to be accepted. The following is what i did. I changed the svn url to http from https

When i tried http i got and error something like http is not supported redirecting to https.

I changed the url to https and it asked me to accept a SSL certificate i accepted it but the same results.

I tried restarting the intelij and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked!! but instead of `to http from https` I found `from https to http` more readable.

Comment: another solution was to run SVN once from command line and manually accept the certificate.