# IntelliJ: SVN auth issue

Tags: svn, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ14 Community Edition. I am trying to check out a project from a SN repository. When I specify https://URL I get this handshake error specifying SSLv3 or TLSv1 version. 
Here is the message:
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Please check Subversion SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1

When I cancel the transaction, I get this message: server cert rejected.

I tried this, but did not help:

Edited /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist (VMOptions) and added this:
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
I also tried this:
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3 -

I also cleared the auth cache.

I would like to continue using IntelliJ, but I am having issues with SVN auth right now. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart IntelliJ.

I have got some issue when trying to checkout or update repo in SVN in PhpStorm. No matter what I changed SSL protocol to any of `all`, `SSLv3` or `TLSv1`. After reading this page [IntelijIdea 14 ssl handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106972/intelijidea-14-ssl-handshake-failure), I just simply restarted my PhpStorm and SVN update works.

Answer (score 0):

Had a same issue. Restart did not help.
I was putting repository path to the `root` not to the `trunk` folder. But when a changed url to trunk I was able successfully check out project. Without having any certificate issues. Hope it helps.