# Cannot curl secure server with openssl 0.1.0

Tags: apache, curl, openssl

I am running a secure site on apache and openssl 1.0.1.

This works fine in the browser, but when I curl the site, I am getting the following error

`curl: (35) error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)`

From what I can find, this is some incompatibility between openssl 0.9.8 on the client, and 1.0.1 on the server.

Is there maybe some server-side configuration in mod_ssl to prevent this error, or would I be best to downgrade to 0.9.8, and if the latter, any advice for doing so on Ubuntu? For example, if I apt-get remove and apt-get install, do I need to reinstall / restart apache for the changes to take effect?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since it is still unanswered:

This is a bug in OpenSSL 0.9.8, but can be fixed (or overridden) in Apache. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8058839 for a fix. Note that the ServerName directive should be identical to the name used by the client (e.g., "localhost" will not work).