# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name while connecting to the https url via groovy

Tags: java, groovy, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, ss

I am trying to acces the https xml url of my application deployed on jdk **1.7.0_25** through my groovy code. But the groovy throws an exception for this line in groovy code -

```
 URL url = new URL("https://my.company.com//path/to/xml")
 URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection()
 def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(url.toString())
 //Parse the XML here....and perform operations
```

**exception javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:unrecognized_name**

As a workaround I tried importing the certificate - my.company.com from the certificate hierarchy **my.company.cer** through the browser to my local keystore where I've my development environment setup. Below is the command -

```
1. keytool -importcert -alias "mycompany-ca" -file my.company.cer
2. keytool -import -file my_company.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -trustcacerts -storepass "changeit"
```

And the certificate was successfully added to the local trust store - "jdk1.6.0_30\jre\lib\security\cacerts". I was able to access the xml via https url via groovy code then. So I tried further importing the same certificate in the server environment's local keystore.

But the problem is this workaround works randomly. Sometimes I am able to access this xml successfully via https url from the server and sometimes I hit the same error randomly without any change in the script.

Do I need to import the root certificate into the local trust store of my server environment?

How do I handle this SSL exception in my groovy itself?

I am sorry I am complete new to this. Any pointers and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0 is pretty much the same, the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8769768/411846 helped me find a workaround.