# Null Pointer Exception while sending mail with attachment through JavaMail API on amazon server in Java Application

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jakarta-mail

while sending a mail with pdf attachment in amazon server using javamail API, Its throwing null pointer exception in the logs. But same code is working in local.

```
public void sendMail(final String mailTo, final String mailSubject, final String mailText, final String filePath, final String fileName) {
    logger.info("Inside sendMail Method...");
    final Properties config = createConfiguration();

    // Creates a mail session. We need to supply username and password for Gmail authentication.
    final Session session = Session.getInstance(config, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(mailFrom, mailPassword);
        }
    });

    // Creates email message
    final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
        message.setSubject(mailSubject);

        final BodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setContent(mailText, contentType);

        final MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);

        if (filePath != null) {
            final MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            final URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(filePath);
                final DataSource source = new URLDataSource(url);
                attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                attachmentPart.setFileName(fileName);
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                logger.error("Malformed URL Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // Send a message
        Transport.send(message);
        logger.info("Mail triggered successfully");
    } catch (final AddressException e) {
        logger.error("Address Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (final MessagingException e) {
        logger.error("Messaging Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please find below the exception generated on amozon server application log.

```
2014-03-20 19:01:30,936 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] INFO            net.app.api.jobs.MailJob - Error in triggering the mail : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:299)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1375)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
at net.app.api.mail.MailTrigger.sendMail(MailTrigger.java:104)
at net.app.api.jobs.MailJob.execute(MailJob.java:41)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Anybody please provide some feasible solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the `DataSource` and `DataHandler` are initialized to correct values and the desired values are passed to it.

Comment: This line is giving the exception: Transport.send(message); from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you can't access the URL in filePath.

Is filePath a "file:" URL?  If so, why not just use a FileDataSource?

Comment: The file path in amazon server is like "https://www.exmaple.com/documents/samplefile.pdf" and we are able to access this filepath locally through browser as well as through code base. I tried with FileDataSource also but given the same error. Any other way can you please suggest ? Thanks.

Comment: The file is on the same machine as the JavaMail application, right?  Assuming it's really a file stored on the server... Make sure you can access the file using a FileInputStream in your application, then use a FileDataSource when creating the message.  If you can't access the file using a FileInputStream, you'll need to debug that problem.  If it's not really a file stored on the server, but is just a resource accessed using a URL, make sure you can access it using URLConnection.getInputStream.

Comment: I had the same stack trace... after updating to a recent mail.jar, I got a more useful message - the file didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the attachment code base part as

```
final MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
final URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(filePath);
    final DataSource source = new URLDataSource(url);
    attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    attachmentPart.setFileName(fileName);
    attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
    attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
} catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
    logger.error("Malformed URL Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The null pointer exception issue got resolved and got a new exception as SSLProtocol Exception and came to know the difference on java jdk's installed in both machines as 1.6 in local machine and 1.7 in amazon cloud. So followed [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0) and now the mail is triggering in both servers as expected.