# JavaMail attachment nullPointer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have test code for my mail sending method. Sending only with html work fine, but I try to add attachment (local file, so "file://..."), and i get that. :

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)

My code  :

```
@Inject
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

...

MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

// html
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setText(SomeHtml, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

// image
MimeBodyPart imageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String fileName = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("chat1.jpg").toString();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
imageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
imageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
multipart.addBodyPart(imageBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);
mailSender.send(message);
```

I've tried to use `MimeMessageHelper`, but i've got same result.
I've tried `source.getInputStream().close()`, i've got `java.io.FileNotFoundException` (but i can find my image when i paste path into browser or explorer)

I don't understand, Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i juste change my code like here [Null Pointer Exception while sending mail with attachment through JavaMail API on amazon server in Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551439/null-pointer-exception-while-sending-mail-with-attachment-through-javamail-api-o)

It's work, but i don't understand the real difference...