# How to disable SNI in Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, sni

I'm attempting to use `requests` to access a remote server over SSL. Unfortunately it's misconfigured such that it responds with the error `TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME` during the SNI handshake, which is ignored by browsers but raises an exception in `requests`.

This appears to be the same issue as this question, but in Python rather than Java:  [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)`

The connection works perfectly in Python 2, which doesn't support SNI. How can I disable SNI in Python 3 so that the connection works?

Comment: Not sure, if it relates, but today I got accross `requests_toolbelt` offereing [SSLAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#ssladapter).

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a way to disable SNI on the `requests` level, but I found a hack that will trick it into thinking SNI isn't supported. Add this code before importing `requests` (not after, or it will be too late):

```
import ssl
ssl.HAS_SNI = False
```