# Java Applet loading SSLProtocolException unrecognized_name on other 443 port

Tags: java, ssl, applet

I encounter a problem with the server from a client. On this server it is 2 installations of our web application. Installation on port 443 and the 8082 are all 2 HTTPS.

On port 443 no problems. On port 8082 when initializing applets there is a java error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.AppFSO.class"

Opening the java console I get:

```
basic: Processus d'écoute de progression ajouté : sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1670865
basic: Processus d'écoute de progression ajouté : sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@c18b02
security: Expected Main URL: https://test.com:8082/applets/uploadHTTP/AppUpload1.8.jar
security: Expected Main URL: https://test.com:8082/applets/FileSystemObject/AppFSO1.8.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://test.com:8082/applets/uploadHTTP/AppUpload1.8.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://test.com:8082/applets/FileSystemObject/AppFSO1.8.jar
network: Connexion de https://test.com:8082/applets/FileSystemObject/AppFSO1.8.jar avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Connexion de https://test.com:8082/applets/uploadHTTP/AppUpload1.8.jar avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Connexion de http://test.com:8082/ avec proxy=DIRECT
network: Connexion de http://test.com:8082/ avec proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

(my applets are signed with a current GlobalSign certificate until 11.30.2017)

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0 helps

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem in apache conf. I replace * by the server name and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I replace

```
NameVirtualHost *:8082
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    ServerName *:8082
```

by

```
NameVirtualHost test.com:8082
<VirtualHost test.com:8082>
    ServerName test.com:8082
```