# What are the security consequences of setting "jsse.enableSNIExtension" to false?

Tags: java, ssl, https, sslhandshakeexception, sslexception

I currently have an application that would make HTTP post request to a lot of URLs. Some of the connections are failing with the following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException:
>   handshake alert:  unrecognized_name   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(ClientHandshaker.java:1410)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2004)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
>     at
>   com.amazon.cba.iopn.test.MainTest.connectWithFallbackIfRequired(MainTest.java:246)
>     at
>   com.amazon.cba.iopn.test.MainTest.createHttpConnection(MainTest.java:201)
>     at com.amazon.cba.iopn.test.MainTest.processLine(MainTest.java:105)
>     at com.amazon.cba.iopn.test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:99)

I figure out after reading other articles from net that this is an issue with the server configuration. The server in reply throws a warning which Java treats as Exception. The workaround is to set **jsse.enableSNIExtension** to "**false**".

- What are the security risk the client exposes, if it sets the **jsse.enableSNIExtension** system property to **false**?

***PS:*** All URLs that we are trying to connect over HTTPS. So, there will be certificate verification.

Comment: Setting 'jsse.enableSNIExtension' to false disables SNI support for your entire application. If you connect to a single domain or a fixed set of domains, none of which support SNI, this shouldn't be an issue. However, if some of your domains use SNI, your app will not be able to connect. A workaround that attempts to thwart the misconfigured SNI check is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884941/4483015

Answer (score 8):

from oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html):

> It enables TLS connections to virtual servers, in which multiple servers for different network names are hosted at a single underlying network address

If you disable  jsse.enableSNIExtension you won't be able to connect to pages under a virtual server

Comment: That is actually not completely accurate. You can have multiple virtual servers of which each one has a separate IP. You can also have single IP, but the same cefticate for all virtual hosts (with alternative names in the certificate or with wildcard certificate).

Comment: [java se8 security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExtension](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExtension)