# How to post JSON in Groovy with standard libraries?

Tags: groovy

What's the easiest way to post JSON to a URL in groovy using only the standard libraries? (ie, without using HttpClient or HttpClientBuilder)

This is a script I'd rather not have to link in lots of other libraries to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def con = "http://endpointUrl".toURL().openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.outputStream.withWriter { writer ->
  writer << jsonString
}

String response = con.inputStream.withReader { Reader reader -> reader.text }
```

Comment: Note that if you are using HTTPS I found that you will likely need this code before hand: System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false"); // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0