# Java "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed" certificate validation error

Tags: java, validation, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to retrieve the index page of a forum that uses SSL certificates using java:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(...);
HtmlPage sectionPage = webClient.getPage("https://rstforums.com/");
```

I've disabled SNI as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0) programmatically prior to invoking any SSL related methods. Following the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore) question and the third from [this](http://keytool%20-import%20-alias%20joe%20-file%20mycert.cer%20-keystore%20mycerts%20-storepass%20changeit) one I added the forum's certificate to the certificate list:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\security>keytool -import -alias RST_CERT -file forums_certificate -keystore cacerts
```

where `forums_certificate` contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The certificate has been successfully added and appears in the keystore when listing its entries:

```
rst_cert, Feb 3, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 25:39:98:FC:FF:DE:2D:24:BC:F0:78:93:D6:2E:5A:55:64:D5:09:8A
```

When I try to rerun the application making a new request, the same error is given:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securi
ty.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certifica
tion path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.jav
a:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.j
ava:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerIm
pl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustMan
agerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1491)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav
a:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:138)
        at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:31)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBu
ilder.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCert
PathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 15 more
```

I have the suggestions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/KB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed) (downloaded SSLPoke) but the error persists. Why isn't the certificate recognized?

Comment: Are you using `HtmlUnit`? If yes, why don't you disable/ignore the SSL check?

Comment: Did you check the content of the certificate? It says "www.rstforums.com" not "forum.com".

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  I did disable it.

Comment: @Rainer Montag In the code it is rstforums.com. Edited it now (the error persists though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to remove and add the certificate to the keystore using openssl (from cygwin (I am working on Win7)).

To retrieve the certificate using openssl:

```
openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect rstforums.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/rst_cert.crt
```

To remove the current `rst_cert` from the store:

```
keytool -delete -alias rst_cert -keystore cacerts
```

To add the certificate downloaded using openssl:

```
keytool -importcert -file ~/example.crt -alias example -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

The certificate downloaded using firefox was apparently invalid.

Comment: This seems to be a good idea. But - openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/rst_cert.crt
gives the following error. #### 
#### Error opening Certificate /proc/3756/fd/63 ####
#### 9072:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/proc/3756/fd/63','rb')
#### 9072:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
#### unable to load certificate 
(Please remove # and read)

Answer (score 0):

For localhost developers,
After hours of doing things like adding certificates to cacert, generating jks files, using InstallCert.java... Here is the solution, ignore the certificate, override the TrustManager, works like a charm:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html