# LinkedIn share preview not working

Tags: linkedin-api

For my site, preview images do not appear in linkedin status updates.

It seems I have all the requisite OGP tags:

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    ...             
<meta property="og:image" content="https://allroadstraveled.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Kozanji_Kyoto.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1080" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="592" />
```

(source of https://allroadstraveled.com/zen-temples-of-kyoto/ )

[image]

Why are preview images not appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem: everything worked except for LinkedIn on our https-only website. The problem was that ServerName and ServerAlias were not set in the Apache config file (default-ssl in our case).

You can use the Twitter card validator to check your SSL-settings (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), if this throws an error adjust your Apache config.

You find additional information here: [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

and here: [Making your site shareable on LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726220/making-your-site-shareable-on-linkedin)