# Making your site shareable on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm having a few issues with making our site shareable on linked in and I'm at a loss.  The og: meta tags all look fine, the facebook scraper picks it up fine, but the linkedIn scraper does not... and the img etc are not on a protected folder or anything like that.

When inspecting the developer tools the get request to the url-preview?url= link shows that the img etc.. aren't there.

The image is less than 1mb, all og: meta tags are obeyed.  The only think that may not be 100% is the image ratio is not 1/4 or 4/1 (it's 2/1)... But that is only a recommendation and not a hard and fast rule.

Does LinkedIn provide something similar to FB (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) where you can test the scraper and re-run it?  Or is there another way to debug this?  Any help appreciated.

https://www.hipla.co.uk (is the page i'm trying to share).

cheers

Comment: Ah... it takes 7 days for LinkedIn's scrapers to re-scrape.... when I scanned this page I missed that point the first time (it's at the bottom): https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Answer (score 2):

It transpires linked in doesn't offer a similar facility to FB or twitter to test the OG meta tags and re-scrape the page.  They cache a page for 7 days and then re-scrape again.  However, you can refresh the linkedIn crawler cache simply by appending GET params to the URL, i.e. https://www.hipla.co.uk?123.

I eventually figured out what our issue was.  We were using a wildcard cert (for multi domain, so we could have a single ssl cert for multiple subdomains) which meant we had to set the server name in the apache default-ssl.conf file, but we had a typo in it for the www instance ... which meant it gave an SSL error (for the linkedIn crawler) which isn't debuggable (if that's a word) using linkedIn but was spotted as we got an SSL error when testing the twitter metadata tags using the twitter card validator.  Hope this helps anyone else who has a typo in their ssl settings.  Note that the ssl error was not visible using a browser(s) as all looked fine.