# Share on LinkedIn with og

Tags: ruby-on-rails, share, linkedin-api

I have rails app. I added og tags for Facebook, google +, and Vkontakte. And I need to add possibility to share to LinkedIn too. But I don't understand why LinkedIn don't pick my OG tags.

My html:

```
= tag :meta, property: 'og:url', content: 'https://myapp.com/app'
= tag :meta, property: 'og:title', content: 'MyApp'
= tag :meta, property: 'og:description', content: 'You can always find a my app !'
= tag :meta, property: 'og:image', content: "https://myapp.com#{image_path('backgrounds/desk.jpg')}"
```

And facebook, g+, vk works perfectly, but linked in don't fetch any information from my website.

Any advise?

Comment: Look this article: [link](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: everything worked except for LinkedIn on our https-only website. The problem was that ServerName and ServerAlias were not set in the Apache config file (default-ssl in our case).

You can use the Twitter card validator to check your SSL-settings (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), if this throws an error adjust your Apache config.

You find additional information here: [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

and here: [Making your site shareable on LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726220/making-your-site-shareable-on-linkedin)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!  You made your post **on March 10, 2017**.  Support for `og:` tags at LinkedIn was only officially added and released **on March 23, 2017**; *the feature just 13 days away!*

The following formats are now all supported...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**Official LinkedIn Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

Works great for me:

[image]

If you want to verify that you have the tags in place correctly in your `<head>` block of HTML, try testing the page you're sharing at [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).