# LinkedIn doesn't recognise og:image

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm really struggling to get LinkedIn to recognise an og:image. My og tags look like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My title here" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/some-page" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description here" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/og-image.png" />
```

So far I've tried:

- checking the og:url matches the current page
- checking the image exists
- adding `prefixprefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` to my HTML tag
- changing that prefix to `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#"`
- checking the site's SSL settings (as per [Share on LinkedIn with og](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720542/share-on-linkedin-with-og))
- ensuring my image is at least 1200x672px
- ensuring my image is under 5MB

I'm not sure what else there is to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Aha – just tried making it a JPG rather than PNG and LinkedIn now sees it. That's kind of shocking but hopefully that'll help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I was serving PNG images. Adding this fixed it for me:

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
```