# WSO2 ESB change host name in request with Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, I have deployed a Porxy Service and I have configured a Proxy in axis2.xml.

I have an issue, because server responses with 400 Bad Request due to ESB change host name to set proxy name in host name field in request.

Is there any property to solve that issue?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: It is a Proxy Service based on WSDL. Its definitions is vary simple, there are not any code.

Example is as given below:

http://pastebin.com/Mp4FmxWk

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue according to [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

I have put "-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false" as property in wso2carbon.sh.