# How to use a custom Keystore in an SSLContext to drive HTTPS connections

Tags: java, authentication, certificate, keystore, sslcontext

I have to be able to specify the certificate and key to be used to authenticate a HTTPS connection in a configuration file (not a system keystore, but user configuration) in a backend system, and have tried the following approach:

- First to encode the user certificate and private key as a PKCS#12 file encoded in Base64 in config. (I have exported the info from `openssl pkcs12` command and converted to base64 format, to be able to read it from a hardwired `String` instance)
- Read that information from an `InputStream` from a `Base64.Decode` and input to `KeyStore#load()` method. (Info is correctly read and `KeyStore` instance stores actually the user info, this has been checked)
- Specify that `KeyStore` as the source of key info, in a `SSLContext.Builder` (from `org.apache.http.conn.ssl` library) (This is what I think is not correctly done)
- Issue a `HTTPS` call to access a client authentication server that authenticates client based on client presented certificate.

The code used to test the connection is shown below:

```
/**
 * $Id: $
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2017 BaseN.
 *
 * All rights reserved.
 */
package net.basen.testing;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;


/**
 * Tester for https connections.
 */
public class CheckSSLAccess {

    /**
     * Main program
     * @param args
     * @throws KeyStoreException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws CertificateException 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
     * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException 
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String ksContents = /* Keystore contents altered intentionally, but correctly reflect a private key and certificate */
             
              "MIIGuQIBAzCCBn8GCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBnAEggZsMIIGaDCCA2cGCSqGSIb3DQEHBqCCA1gw"
            + "ggNUAgEAMIIDTQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCiqGSIb3DQEMAQYwDgQIYhJ5Aj443RACAggAgIID"
            + "IFm66yYJF7tTq7QTyyAVMJKEz5D1E0fueAVYE2jEHLKqrHcXdyW0Iw0+BZMKJ0zLtEmfZnl2"
            + "IYyHi9TG0olkijITq/u9pNyHBZOB0zzqiF5ddl76tJWfYGiuM2AQDLZ1+AbC9niSpKJd5Rrz"
            + "wlYjJmuJhRusMtDe73Yjtf+N1WQycRgQhPwhk5kdZFgUBLOhVtnTnwBPxOp7hhIHbDSvC8qU"
            + "2ktmQWWA1wY5Se4Mn1/CEJXzJnvElWLiSdf97PCPWOrwkg1n0/QqAvxqDQ9Ctb20PSHOSwYF"
            + "EQmU2gc59uL+4I/8eLXhCEowozuKQdTbLrn3uzl6lPzLo+rB2DEYdixXwCCTaOqP1Wc7WtId"
            + "DYS8aSZwSbD+ErnD5nFwqwlABI9CnIWRbUdHyMvE1ZtcF+7wNwg2lK4wroPuX6uzREmIt5qy"
            + "lGIj29T+RqvL+g9IjFRTo6udWl23caf6P7kaeRe7SWFfIJEqx0378uucBIh8aeTnpM+CeH3N"
            + "RziOMJp7kZ0ICnEbKhPjRYnN7eN1vk5jeMUZ7J4GctAeON51phWHeZKW4326DFg12lEJpUCJ"
            + "5r47POuAaW34qizc77/AgeTpoAvoKQ1ZkXndh/3Gvu0uUNAxS5uLEOZ5L7MxPvAHJo7e/ngM"
            + "KbBeWfekC5wPIyaPJhMwrvMt0D9wbpWTSge1X7Brx2TK94q97bYP/evjbbRAhUBZmcENOAtF"
            + "mIyUf20SoAxeMY8jdgs4pS3+spQygDu0STIVFs4rHErKG+lF8p6HTKHPZYe8S0N53OsG3xT7"
            + "ihc2IO+yr3wtyZ3lhg69JQfvDtmzN00DEjcIz6tl9rGN/bZlgd7GQmgjlo+NbnduGnipePZU"
            + "+NVD58l5JXz65wG/xT/QSVXckhXwYRcaUXIi7wPTZaOORDF9j02mS3C6/GlQYLD+/2KYtAVP"
            + "JweU1dhP3cqn2nfv7tyiroDWoAhH9UrnksampwgwPS5UG+UY1tioQ8ji7G4QcWLgDdl8/V12"
            + "jGNurjsIpGOyq5TogtzYNKLCqH2a+Q1Zx/nn0Z7wF71gd3MiUFFGmDIHwt/eMIIC+QYJKoZI"
            + "hvcNAQcBoIIC6gSCAuYwggLiMIIC3gYLKoZIhvcNAQwKAQKgggKmMIICojAcBgoqhkiG9w0B"
            + "DAEDMA4ECHTd/kkMd4hlAgIIAASCAoB3BTQ3SUHu94CTpt6g9MBrUB5kZWH+k+a8KWtLeZzH"
            + "a2Rgi0uhCzePnQAinhPJLTBB9oQHcHsJALg7yUpm8oN2yb/X1CjRnQ/O3vjzhxDZxp0NjvvG"
            + "vXPPCCYiIDCIhp+PHggMNTv5hrB/vcpWXCBCE6ekE/KFu6K8g7+H/5LspRNfepc+xYhm9TkJ"
            + "WUmmcmQ445RCDypRrC7s6dmj3nP8wOFCZdj4YjAeFvWga86AVeRyk/AA14E0LOaRx/1WgO1E"
            + "lzXCiI+wPNUiO0YokIfo7JatdDBqVgQnlzXApgy01MhIlrMfd/f18nkpICcel772XCnosQmG"
            + "kb2mwNMN6CZ23LgxhKGuMuik04/FSNZPnOqKoZEIfGo9QM+DkBwR/sxfBH2QrxrY6jP/ajIZ"
            + "afhBXLIXV3gZc1G1xUseJCDvlMTXLu8XDVFPbVijbqsBJHA9zn4dXEntp69HYQR5W2DAASYh"
            + "ct604nz2Ucz/Bs+z4zIOo18tjmLXJNd7YMhgRZmv+aYGWe3J2tz3OHpmfV6QKqISCwFOuqgz"
            + "oQWRDHYxZ2FuVMYoUBLsyFM88pwdD2Vl/ylzmXo7y5GuYtV0LYvuNz+xOPXWbhn63cwtW2ci"
            + "MBHRBvSg+lbZLs6XKamUra4kaGYgvrtiFToZiQyC5+hixLTOELLR0c6r+cu47ndufjAgZ6JS"
            + "CwkwoVJfpmKEtlpceMcomSr5cF9Ch/VuHmSUAv95oZl89oLARydhTYOov62AXdvys/gsZIRl"
            + "CwnXiigqTsIv19XONdiyRQKX/Xb2vxDflpJI2vS98hDg2tjOzwDeP8ca7XGUrhBzeMIqTX/y"
            + "6WnuDLvZwCcny5lqCSdoMSUwIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkVMRYEFLVCIUOKJgdfLQONh2cgK4guMkgw"
            + "MDEwITAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBSJDAJ5CJ60ujZK9azvjW1WukvlvwQI+GVGxf0ZtlYCAggA";

        try {
            InputStream is = Base64.getMimeDecoder().wrap( new ByteArrayInputStream( ksContents.getBytes() ) );
            KeyStore kst = KeyStore.getInstance( "pkcs12" );
            kst.load( is, null );
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() )
                .init( kst, null );
            SSLContext.setDefault( SSLContexts.custom()
                                   .loadTrustMaterial(kst)
                                   .loadKeyMaterial( kst, null )
                                   .build() );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient cl = HttpClients.createDefault();
            /* server address has been also altered to protect access privacy */
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet( "https://www.server.com/autheticated_url" );
            CloseableHttpResponse resp = cl.execute( get );
            System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine());
            Header[] headers = resp.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++)
                System.out.println(headers[i]);
            System.out.println();
            InputStream in = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int n;
            while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                System.out.write( buffer, 0, n );
            }
            if (n < 0) {
                System.err.println( "n == " + n );
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

} /* CheckSSLAccess */
```

The library issues the following exception, when negotiating `SSL` credentials with the server, the same as if no user certificate is being used.  I don't know exactly what is missing in this code for the client to select the proper certificate and negotiate correctly with the server.

Sorry, but due to project issues, the certificates shown in the example have been changed to newly generated ones, and also the URL of the server to access to.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(ClientHandshaker.java:1438)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at net.basen.testing.CheckSSLAccess.main(CheckSSLAccess.java:109)
```

The question is

What should be missing in the `SSLContext` initialization for it to select (or to link the `SSLContext` to the actual HTTPS call) the `KeyStore` credentials in the HTTPS call?

## EDIT

After activating the option in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645) and debug mode, the user certificate is never considered in the ssl handshake, so I'm afraid this question has nothing to do with the referred one.  For some reason, the hanshake stops on the server certificate exchange and client certificate is never exchanged:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[...]
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
[...]
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1471524485 bytes = { 109, 133, 165, 223, 114, 170, 197, 226, 115, 115, 12, 46, 74, 145, 95, 17, 242, 119,
57, 167, 76, 6, 147, 14, 32, 63, 62, 177 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
[...]
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1,
sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1,
secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA,
SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 195
0000: 01 00 00 BF 03 03 58 B6   AF 85 6D 85 A5 DF 72 AA  ......X...m...r.
[...]
00B0: 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03   03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00C0: 02 01 01                                           ...
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 195
[Raw write]: length = 200
0000: 16 03 03 00 C3 01 00 00   BF 03 03 58 B6 AF 85 6D  ...........X...m
[...]
00B0: 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01   04 03 04 01 03 03 03 01  ................
00C0: 02 03 02 01 02 02 01 01                            ........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 31                                     ....1
[Raw read]: length = 49
0000: 02 00 00 2D 03 01 58 B6   AF 85 5B 50 5E 9A C0 D5  ...-..X...[P^...
0010: 74 38 A3 6F F8 14 C1 F1   0E 35 E0 D8 66 4A 13 23  t8.o.....5..fJ.#
0020: 1E BC 39 EE 70 8D 00 00   2F 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  ..9.p.../.......
0030: 00                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 49
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1471524485 bytes = { 91, 80, 94, 154, 192, 213, 116, 56, 163, 111, 248, 20, 193, 241, 14, 53, 224, 216, 102,
74, 19, 35, 30, 188, 57, 238, 112, 141 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 49
0000: 02 00 00 2D 03 01 58 B6   AF 85 5B 50 5E 9A C0 D5  ...-..X...[P^...
0010: 74 38 A3 6F F8 14 C1 F1   0E 35 E0 D8 66 4A 13 23  t8.o.....5..fJ.#
0020: 1E BC 39 EE 70 8D 00 00   2F 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  ..9.p.../.......
0030: 00                                                 .
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 08 5F                                     ...._
[Raw read]: length = 2143
0000: 0B 00 08 5B 00 08 58 00   04 AC 30 82 04 A8 30 82  ...[..X...0...0.
0010: 03 90 A0 03 02 01 02 02   01 13 30 0D 06 09 2A 86  ..........0...*.
0020: 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05   00 30 81 92 31 0B 30 09  H........0..1.0.
[...]
0810: 3F 7F 8E 25 F0 6C 0E 10   75 D9 D6 C6 51 77 AE 1D  ?..%.l..u...Qw..
0820: 96 0A E9 72 1B 65 2F C5   E4 96 20 67 0E 75 76 E0  ...r.e/... g.uv.
0830: D5 42 27 4B 81 22 15 C4   F9 7E A2 78 24 91 A4 A2  .B'K.".....x$...
0840: A7 96 1A B4 D0 D7 88 94   B5 36 B7 B3 19 78 37 E1  .........6...x7.
0850: C2 2E 28 61 D4 E0 4B 42   20 27 6C 99 40 A2 8E     ..(a..KB 'l.@..
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2143
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=admin@actility.com, CN=rms.poc1.actility.com, OU=Actility, O=Actility, ST=FRANCE, C=FR
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus:
2292398721841540[...]592209023
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Apr 03 15:25:07 CEST 2014,
               To: Wed Mar 29 15:25:07 CEST 2034]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=admin@actility.com, CN=m2m.actility.com, OU=Actility, O=Actility, L=Paris, ST=FRANCE, C=FR
  SerialNumber: [    13]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 1F 16 1D 4F 70 65 6E   53 53 4C 20 47 65 6E 65  ....OpenSSL Gene
0010: 72 61 74 65 64 20 43 65   72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74  rated Certificat
0020: 65                                                 e


[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
[EMAILADDRESS=admin@actility.com, CN=m2m.actility.com, OU=Actility, O=Actility, L=Paris, ST=FRANCE, C=FR]
SerialNumber: [    9d5d3f4c 2ee0bcd9]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0B 82 48 98 6B E2 66 02   2E 30 7E 3C 0E 55 18 9E  ..H.k.f..0.<.U..
0010: DF 78 BC E9                                        .x..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: C7 E2 0C 87 AE AF 97 E8   DD 9C 9F B5 1E C0 48 AA  ..............H.
[...]
00E0: 10 AB 42 B8 C2 F9 42 C8   BC 60 99 12 FE A1 CE 9F  ..B...B..`......
00F0: 2C 9A 66 DF AE 03 88 61   9A 24 0B 1A D2 89 22 EA  ,.f....a.$....".

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=admin@actility.com, CN=m2m.actility.com, OU=Actility, O=Actility, L=Paris, ST=FRANCE, C=FR
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus:
2828950521283455293132606[...]047773313891689356150673882060816455169139045423472889
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Apr 03 15:23:19 CEST 2014,
               To: Wed Mar 29 15:23:19 CEST 2034]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=admin@actility.com, CN=m2m.actility.com, OU=Actility, O=Actility, L=Paris, ST=FRANCE, C=FR
  SerialNumber: [    9d5d3f4c 2ee0bcd9]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: A7 FB 5B 7F 90 9D 31 85   CC CA 1D 19 C5 B6 34 2A  ..[...1.......4*
[...]
00F0: E1 C2 2E 28 61 D4 E0 4B   42 20 27 6C 99 40 A2 8E  ...(a..KB 'l.@..

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E                               .......
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
[....]
java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: may be is a misconfiguration of server name and you need to disable SNI extension. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0

Comment: @pedrofb, Tried the option you mention, but without result.  The same error was received when tried from `curl(1)` until I properly used the appropiate certificate and key, then everything went ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized\_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

Comment: @Hugo, sorry, but for the moment, upgrade to 1.7 is not possible.... better knowledge on what is going on would be appreciated.  I'll take a survey at the link you post, anyway.

Comment: Anyway, the error was the same with `curl(1)` (`unrecognized_name`) until I used properly the appropiate certificate and key requested by the server (it is a server authenticated HTTPS request)  Some advice in how to check what and how client certificates are negotiated (as this is what I suspect is not being handled) would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your keystore contain the client certificate and the server root CA?Try to add -Djavax.net.debug=all to debug the ssl connection. Try also to set explicitly the `SSLSocketFactory` in `CloseableHttpClient`. I do not know whether Apache http client is going the default keystore you have set

Comment: @pedrofb, no, it hasn't, but I decided not to include it as the server is supposed to have all the chain, as the server accepts the connection when used by `curl(1)` with the same key info.  I'll try to use that property to see if something arises in the debug.  Perhaps some hints on what's going on.

Comment: @pedrofb, from the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` I get all the certificates added to the chain, but nothing about the one I try to use.  So, as I supposed, it's not getting to the proper `SSLContext` instance, or I'm not selecting it properly to be used in the connection.

Comment: Since you are using the same p12 for keystore and truststore, you need to  include the client certificate (private key and public cert) and the server root CA. The error you have is not because the client can not find the server certificate because it probably fails before. But you will need it later

Comment: @pedrofb, I have activated debug mode as you suggested and the user certificate does not appear anywhere.... I'm afraid I have not inked the Keystore generated in the code with the actual SSLContext used.  I'm afraid the connection is rejecting the server certificate, despite the server offers the complete certificate chain to the client.  But for the moment, I have no means to extract the certificate chain offered by the server and store it locally to be able to accept the server as trusted.