# SNI missing with jaxws-maven-plugin generated soap client in java8(openjdk 1.8.0_101) and wildfly 10.1 environement

Tags: java-8, soap-client, wildfly-10, sslhandshakeexception, sni

Here is the problem

I have an jaxws-maven-plugin (version 2.5, jaxws-tools 2.3.0) generated code for an wsdl (for a soap service)

It generated code with @WebServiceClient (javax.xml.ws java1.8) client.

When I run this client in Junit against an site, everything is normal, I get the sslconnection correct, and received response. But when I runned the application using this client towards the same site in wildfly 10.1, I actually got the SSLHandshakeException, unrecognized_name, which is an indication on SNI was missing. I had an own client I wrote using HttpsURLConnection, it works fine. So I am really stuck why this happens.

The code generated from maven looks like following (I can only have peudo code)

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "service_name", targetNamespace = "https://namespace.com/xxxxxx/v2", wsdlLocation = "/wsdl/targetwsdl.wsdl")
public class DTServerModuleServiceV2
    extends Service
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see one parameter which could change this behaviour. From the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization) , try `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` as by default it is set to true.
There is one long discussion and one technical explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884941/7748072) , but your question is not really a duplicate.
Let us know if it is resolved.

By the way, your Java version is old and known to have SSL bugs.

Comment: I am using java 8, and found the root cause, it is cxf togather with java 8 have a bug that turn SNI off...