# SNI : SSLHandshakeException unrecognized_name

Tags: karate, sslhandshakeexception, sni

I have the following error when trying to contact some website :

```
10:29:32.228 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name, http call failed after 35 milliseconds for URL: https://{redacted}
10:29:32.229 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name
```

I have found the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884941/10791639

I edited `karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java` L125, removing the comment from this line :

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

But I still have the same problem as before. I haven't found a public website that is requiring strict Server Name Indication to reproduce my problem.

Comment: can you try switching to `karate-jersey` instead of apache. as far as I know the `NoopHostnameVerifier` is supposed to do it  - but only for SSL: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java#L153

Comment: I didn't manage to make karate-jersey work. We found a different solution though, which I detailed in the answer below, could you take a look please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution by changing something in `karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java` :

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
```

becomes

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SslConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
```

@Peter, do you think a parameter to use strict or lenient SSL connection can be a possibility?

Comment: `LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory` is code in Karate - ideally this should be fixed to make your scenario work - do you think you can debug this and figure ? refer https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/385

Comment: I found this issue after I posted this solution, as I was trying to figure what would be the best way to fix it. You can reopen it and assign it to me.

Comment: Adrien - can you comment on that ticket once, else I can't assign it (some GitHub permissions thing)

Comment: someone reported that `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` works in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69123671/143475