# Karate - Getting fatal alert: unrecognized_name when trying to send post request using proxy

Tags: proxy, karate, sslhandshakeexception

I have an existing project using karate-junit5:1.1.0 to test an API.  When ran locally from my laptop everything is working as expected.  I'm implementing the same test in Jenkins and we need to use a proxy server to connect to external URLs from our Jenkins nodes.

Prior to updating the test to use a proxy I get an error like this attempting to connect to the external URL:

```
15:17:46.486 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to <url redacted>:443 [<url redacted>] failed: connect timed out, http call failed after 30198 milliseconds for url: https://<url redacted>
15:17:46.488 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:token/GetAuthToken.feature:16
```

Using the karate documentation I updated the project to use a proxy globally in the karate-config.js file:
`karate.configure('proxy', 'http://<url redacted>');`

After making this change, I am now seeing a different error when the test attempts to connect to the external URL:

```
12:38:57.391 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name, http call failed after 1514 milliseconds for url: https://<url redacted>
12:38:57.392 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:token/GetAuthToken.feature:16
```

In searching online I couldn't find much information about this new error.  Any idea on how I can resolve this so I can run my tests in external facing environments?  Thanks

Comment: this sounds like something you have to solve on your own and work with your network / ops folks. look out for any HTTPS related problems: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+proxy also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55359395/143475

Comment: Thank you for the info.

I found a work-around for the time being.  I updated my jenkins pipeline script to pass in this parameter:
`-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`

Which appears to have gotten around the issue and my tests are running