# Hostname in certificate didn't match on wildcard cert

Tags: java, apache, ssl

This may be an apache/server configuration, or it might require a Java solution.   On my server I have a few subdomains.  I force https on all subdomains and I have a wildcard ssl certificate that is used for all subdomains.

When I go to https://myapp1.myvendor.com and view the certificate in the browser I see the following common name:

CN = *.myvendor.com

I also have a Java program that posts to https://myapp1.myvendor.com/post.php however when I post from Java using:

```
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://myapp1.myvendor.com/post.php");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I get the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: 
<myapp1.myvendor.com> != <myvendor.com> OR <myvendor.com> OR <www.myvendor.com>
```

What strikes me as odd is that it is trying to match myvendor.com or www.myvendor.com not *.myvendor.com.  I do have a certificate installed for myvendor.com, but I stopped using it in favor of the wildcard cert.

Any suggestions?  Do you need more information?

Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/27c7d7842bf94d.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my_cert.crt

 ServerName myapp1.myvendor.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/myvendor/myapp1/src/
 ErrorLog /var/www/logs/myapp1/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/logs/myapp1/access.log combined
 <Directory /var/www/myvendor/myapp1/src/>
         AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also found this in a different config file that IS loaded:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/local.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/local.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my_local_cert.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I think it is getting this cert because this cert has:

```
subject Alternative name:
 DNS Name=myvendor.com
 DNS Name=www.myvendor.com
```

which matches the error from Java.  If this is the case my question is why is Java getting this cert as opposed to the one that the browser gets?

Comment: 95% your myapp1.myvendor.com points to server you don't expect. I.e. your proxy settings/hosts file make domain to point somewhere else... Or myapp1.myvendor.com is configured to use different cert than you expect.

Comment: Or your server does SNI and Java isn't giving it the info it needs to choose the right cert.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov See my edit.  Does my edit make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SNI, e.g. multiple https servers on the same IP with different certificates. In this case have a look at [Server Name Indication (SNI) on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361090/server-name-indication-sni-on-java) how to use SNI in Java.