# Java SNIServerName support in Java 7

Tags: java, ssl, sni

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), Java 1.7 should support SNIServerName, but as per [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) there is no such class in their javax.net.ssl package.Can someone please clarify this? Will I have to use Java 8 API to use SNIServerName class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support is there, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html:

> Server Name Indication (SNI) for JSSE client: The Java SE 7 release
>   supports the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension in the JSSE
>   client. SNI is described in RFC 4366. This enables TLS clients to
>   connect to virtual servers.

However, it is implemented in a different way. For example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119 discusses this. The relevant quote might be

> Java 8 has a completely different SNI API provided out of
>   javax.net.ssl package

So yes, you won't have that class with Java 7, and you will "have to use Java 8 API to use SNIServerName class", like you asked.

For discussion on how to use SNI with Java 7, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361090/server-name-indication-sni-on-java).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I needed to enable/disable SNI at runtime for [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0/14884941#14884941). Since option to set SNI parameters is not available directly in Java 7 , I will be over riding the createSocket() method name for SSLSocketFactory with hostname empty for disabling SNI.